# How do I export photos from my iPhone 6 to my Western Digital external hard drive for backup copies?

Tags: iphone, backup, photos, external-disk

How do I export photos from my iPhone 6 to my Western Digital external hard drive using my Mac? I need to clear up space on my phone already and can't believe how frustrating it is trying to figure this out.

Comment: You should say whether you're using a Mac with OS X or Windows

Comment: I would strongly recommend Image Capture (`/Applications/Image Capture.app`)

Answer (score 1):

Open /Applications/Image Capture.app, select your iPhone, then select your WD as the destination.

Then use Image Capture's delete button to erase all the photos from your phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a **Mac system**, you can use Photos to import the photo from the iPhone to your computer or in an external HD.

You need only to specify the location of the Photos Library folders. Then each time you connect the iPhone you can import only the new photos that have never been imported.

---

Otherwise, if you are using a **Windows system** when you connect your device to the PC, you should automatically see the device connected in the explorer and so you can open the folder and copy the photo as you prefer.
If this does't happen, be sure to:

- have unlocked your iPhone device using your passcode;
- make sure that your iPhone device trusts the computer that you're using.

Sometimes, when you import photos and videos from your device to your computer, some might be rotated incorrectly. To play videos on your computer at the correct orientation, use iTunes for Windows.

---

In both the procedures, if you copy the photos without transferring them, you'll have a security backup.